# Error message shows up in terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, shell

Every time I fire up a terminal window, I get the following error message:

> bash: exxport: command not found

I know I misspelled aa symlink somewhere, but I can't find it. Is there any way to locate the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
which exxport
```

should show you what it's trying to run.

Comment: Thanks, found it right before hiding in my .bashrc file and fixed it, but your solution is appreciated

Comment: How did that help? You already now that "exxport" doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at your `.bashrc`, `.bash_login`, or `.bash_profile` files. In one of them I assume the misspelled export can be found.